# Database Stuck in a Single User Mode in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2016

Our new DBA has taken the database into a single user mode to perform the detach- attach operation but by mistake he closed the sesion.
And ever since then nobody is able to access that database.

I tried to find the session ID by using sp_who2 but it is not showing any session ID on that database.

I am using "SQL Server 2016 Standard Edition" on "Windows server 2016".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> By using the the dynamic view "sys.dm_tran_locks" we can find out the
>   active sessions of the database which is stuck in a single user mode
>   as follows:

--Query to find the session_id

```
SELECT request_session_id FROM sys.dm_tran_locks 

WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID('YourDatabaseName')
```

> Now kill the session ID found by above query as follows:

```
-- kill all the processes which are using your database with following query:

    KILL spid
```

> Bring the database into a multi_user mode by using following query:

```
USE Master
GO
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

> Bring the database online.

```
USE Master
Go
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabaseName SET online
Go
```

> Check the status of the database by using following Query and your Database should be back to normal / multi user mode and online.

```
select * from sys.databases where name ='YourDatabaseName'
```

Answer (score 9):

Below is the working solution of the problem,

SSMS in general uses several connections to the database behind the scenes.

**You will need to kill these connections before changing the access mode.**(I have done it with **EXEC(@kill);** in the code template below.)

Then,

Run the following SQL to **set the database in MULTI_USER mode.**

```
USE master
GO
DECLARE @kill varchar(max) = '';
SELECT @kill = @kill + 'KILL ' + CONVERT(varchar(10), spid) + '; '
FROM master..sysprocesses 
WHERE spid > 50 AND dbid = DB_ID('<Your_DB_Name>')
EXEC(@kill);

GO
SET DEADLOCK_PRIORITY HIGH
ALTER DATABASE [<Your_DB_Name>] SET MULTI_USER WITH NO_WAIT
ALTER DATABASE [<Your_DB_Name>] SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

To switch back to Single User mode, you can use:

```
ALTER DATABASE [<Your_DB_Name>] SET SINGLE_USER
```

This should work. Happy coding!!

Thanks!!

Comment: This should land in every SQL toolbox. You saved my day!

Comment: @MarcinŚmiałek Nice to hear that. It should help other techies as well.